# Fetch record based on string that is present in a field

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, query-optimization, postgresql-9.1

I'm using the following query to fetch records from database. The row that exists in database and the column `question` contains: `"How are we going to do solve this. Is it complex?"`

I'm using the following query to fetch the data.

```
SELECT * FROM TRENDING WHERE question ILIKE '%how are we%' ;
```

The issue is that, the above query works only if those three words are present in database. If I use additional word as following, the query does not work. For instance, the following query does not work

```
SELECT * FROM TRENDING WHERE question ILIKE '%how are we doing %' ;
```

How can I sort this out? I want it to fetch any record that might contain these words that are being queried?

Comment: Well, it seems your table contains 'how are we `g`oing to...` and you are querying for 'how are we `d`oing`, so it makes sense that you don't get that specific record returned.

Comment: You could try asking for something that DOES MATCH with a record in the system ?